# SVG image is escaping the SVG boundary

Tags: angularjs, html, css, svg, ionic-framework

I am using SVG to display profile picture of the user in one of the Ionic applications. The image sometimes escapes the SVG boundary when I navigate to the screen. I also have attached the screenshots of the same.[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaZlf.png)....
[Correct or intended working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7jNJ.png)

```
 <svg viewBox="0 0 120 100" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden" ng-click="openProfileModal()">
                    <defs>
                        <clipPath id="hexagon_clip">
                          <path id="hexagon" d="M38,2 
                               L82,2 
                               A12,12 0 0,1 94,10 
                               L112,44 
                               A12,12 0 0,1 112,56
                               L94,90       
                               A12,12 0 0,1 82,98
                               L38,98
                               A12,12 0 0,1 26,90
                               L8,56
                               A12,12 0 0,1 8,44
                               L26,10
                               A12,12 0 0,1 38,2" />
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    <image ng-href="{{ userPics.photo1 }}" xlink:href="" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#hexagon_clip)" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
                    <use xlink:href="#hexagon" x="0" y="0" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" />
                </svg>
```

note: userPics.photo1 -> it is url of the image which I am loading using AngularJS.

I tried applying the style overflow: hidden to SVG, but image still exit the boundary of SVG. I am new to using SVG. Thanks in advance guys :)